# Modal Verbs Will_Would differences

Tags: modal-verbs, will-would

1). In the context of disease management, it is not the case that one drug **would** work for the entire population and a single one **would be** useful for that patient’s lifetime.

2). In the context of disease management, it is not the case that one drug **will** work for the entire population and a single one **will be** useful for that patient’s lifetime.

Will_Would is always a confusing topic for me. I know would has two different uses 1)As the past form of will 2) Hypothetical forms

Here what is the unstated hypothetical condition in the first sentence??

What is the difference in meaning between these two sentences??

Comment: The use of a single drug is the hypothetical condition.  if we did try to use just one, it wouldn't work.

Answer (score 1):

In the first example the writer is describing a general situation. They do not expect this to happen generally for any disease or any drug although it might in a specific case.

In the second case the writer is describing a specific situation. We know that for this disease no drug works for everybody and if it does work for someone it will not work for that patient for ever.

Having said all that the difference is quite small and if someone used the wrong one it would usually be obvious from the context what they meant.